# Bug with a Steam Game; Motorsport Manager, unable to find the source of the bug

Tags: technical-issues, mods, motorsport-manager

this issue is seemingly very complex, I am open to any suggestion. Even from those who have no played the game.

I started playing the game Motorsport Manager from Steam the other week. After completing my first championship I decided to delve into modding. Modding for the game is done via .TxT documents that the game references. I edited the documents and all worked fine, however a few days ago, a game ruining bug started.
The bug causes the AI to never have fuel in their car at race start.
The game is made in unity and coded in C#.
The game hasn't been updated since 2017.

Currently I have tried;
Reinstalling the game.
Manually replacing the files with files from the base game downloaded to another PC.
Using my account on another PC with cloud sync (Which it worked fine on).
Manually deleting the 'active mods' file.
Deleting all cloud sync data.
Resetting my PC to factory settings and reinstalling windows.
I have also verified the files on Steam.

None of these attempts worked. On my PC the game is broken but not on anyone else's PC.

If anyone has any suggestions I am open to try anything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your documents and/or appdata folders for game data there as well to remove? Do you have another user profile on that same machine you could test with?

Comment: @Sorean yes I checked those locations and deleted them. I have tried another account on my PC (checked it was working fine on the other PC first) and it did not work on my PC.

Comment: Steam has a "verify integrity of game files" option (or something similar). Did you try this as well?

Comment: Another user account, not another steam account. The account you log onto the computer with, not the account you use to log into Steam.

Comment: @Sorean my bad misunderstood, I will need to make one as I am the only one who uses this PC

Comment: @AdamV yes I did my apologies that was meant to be in the post I will add it now

Comment: @Sorean created a new user with a new Microsoft account, installed steam and used a different Steam account, and the bug still persists :/

Comment: What version of windows are the working and non working computers using? Could be a bad windows update.

Comment: Both computers are running; Windows 10 Home Version 1903

Comment: It seems very odd that a full factory reset did not fix the issue.Did you keep the data during the reset or just wipe it completely?

Comment: @Sorean Wiped it completely

Comment: Not gonna lie, that seems really odd that wiping the machine didn't fix the issue. That said it could be a failed Visual C++ version that's missing. Check installed ones on the working machine and see if it's missing on the non working machine.

Comment: I will do that tomorrow morning and get back to you, just heading off to bed.

Comment: @Sorean sorry late reply have been busy, the C++ versions are the same, I decided I will buy a new SSD and install a fresh copy of windows then try it there, will update my post when that has been tried.